# Creation of events in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to create some scheduler events in mongoDB , somewhat like the events in mysql. The event will delete my data in the collection once a day on some criteria. Can someone tell me what is the best way to create it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a cron entry with console javascript call like below:

> mongo localhost:27017/test myjsfile.js

more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/)

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong.1)I will create a serverside javascript file and keep it on the server where mongodb is present 2) i will create a shell script to call this file like you described

Comment: @user2361591 - just realised my typo calling serverside insted of console side - apologies - there is no need for server-side js - all can be in myjsfile.js.